# How to use EhCache (local) and RedisCache (remote) in the same spring boot project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis, ehcache

I have a spring boot project that need local and remote caching. I am trying to use ehcache for local and Redis for remote, but I can't configure both to work together.

I am also trying to use PubSub as Redis Caching, because this one will be seen by others computers.

At this moment, Redis is storing all caching instead of just what I want to.

Comment: What do you mean by local and remote. You want to use different caching topology for different caches or you wanna cache the same object remotely but wanna have local copy of the same cache?

Comment: Hi, @Mesut. I have 3 servers running the API. Each one has to store local cache (I'm trying to use EhCache for that). However, there are one or more caches that should to be shared through all servers (tried to use PubSub as Redis for that).

When I try to configure both of them, Spring Boot ignores Redis and run only with EhCache.

Comment: I see. I suggest you to use hazelcast embedded mode if you wanna share data between microservices. If you wanna keep cache out of your api microservices than you can use client/server where you can keep a separate cache cluster and connect to the cluster via hazelcast cluster. I don't see a much necessity to use two different products for your use case?
Are your API microservices containerized?